# how I test useEffect with isLoading state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-component, react-state-management

I want to build test when the isLoading state change the component.
I know in the class component there is the way by do setState with enzyme, but I would like to know how I can do it here.

```js
const Spacex = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [upComingLaunches, setUpComingLaunches] = useState([]);
    const [Launchpad, setLaunchpad] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        let tempData;
        SpaceXNextLaunche()
            .then(data => {
                setUpComingLaunches(data);
                tempData = data;
                return LaunchPad()
            }).then(dataLaunch => {
                const foundTheLaunch = dataLaunch.docs.filter((Launch, index) => {
                    return tempData.id === Launch.id
                });
                setLaunchpad(foundTheLaunch);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
    }, [])
    if (isLoading) return <LoadingComp />
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="upcoming-launches">
                <h1 className={styles.title}>upcoming launche</h1>
                <div className={styles.CountDownWarrper}>
                    {Object.keys(upComingLaunches).length > 0 ?
                        <Card className={styles.CountDownCard}>
                            <div className={styles.MissionName}>{upComingLaunches.name}</div>
                            <div className={styles.gridBadges}>
                                <div className={styles.CountDown}><CountDownClock upComingLaunches={upComingLaunches} /></div>
                                <div className={styles.badgeFlex}><img className={styles.badge} src={upComingLaunches.links["patch"]["small"]} alt="mission patch" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <GoogleMap
                                mapVisiblity={(e) => setOpen(!open)}
                                open={open}
                                placeName={Launchpad[0].launchpad.full_name} />
                        </Card>
                        : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Spacex;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to test functional components is to test the actual functions' behaviour, not their implementation. In your case that would be mocking the `SpaceXLaunche()` to return its data after some timeout, eg:

```
function SpaceXLauncheMock() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve(data), 1500);
    });
}

const SpaceXLaunche = jest.spyOn(SpaceXLaunche.prototype, 'SpaceXLaunche')
    .mockImplementation(SpaceXLauncheMock);
```

then, you'd test your consequence of `isLoading` - the presence or absence of `LoadingComp`, initially, and again after the timeout (don't forget to put `done` as the test case's argument):

```
expect(component.contains(<LoadingComp />)).toBe(true);

setTimeout(() => {
    expect(component.contains(<LoadingComp />)).toBe(false);

    done();
}, 2000);
```